# Access query parameter with or condition

Tags: ms-access-2007

I want to know how we can accept one parameter from the two columns with OR condition. I want to ask for either PRN no or roll number and show the result.I am trying following query but won't work,

```
SELECT StudentInfo.*, StudentInfo.PRNNo, StudentInfo.StudentRollNo
FROM StudentInfo
WHERE (((StudentInfo.PRNNo)=[Enter PRN No :]) OR ((StudentInfo.StudentRollNo)=[Enter Roll No :]));
```

Here AND condition works properly and asks for both the PRN no and Roll No.But i want ask either PRN or roll no, how we can achieve this

Comment: When you say it "won't work", in what way is it not working?

Comment: It does not allow that syntax..we cannot add OR like this..Is there different way or is that not possible at all?

Comment: What is the exact error message?